# Solve the following ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following ODE

> $$(y-x)\left(1+x^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=n\left(1+y^2 \right)^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

I have tried substituting $y=\tan \theta$ and $x=\tan \phi$ but can't do it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is $n$ here?

Comment: Maple has found a solution

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: Can you post a detailed solution?